# rehosting docker application from VM to Azure Web app

Tags: azure, docker

Apologies in advance my experience on docker is pretty limited.
I have a web application that's been deployed a long time ago as a docker container (actually 4 containers in total but that's irrelevant), it's hosted on a linux VM in azure.

I want to get rid of the VM (difficult to maintain and subject to vulnerabilities) and rehost the application to either an Azure Web app/docker or an Azure docker container (not sure what the different is).
What I've done so far is extracting the images of the running/deployed application from the VM into .tar archive and copied the files locally.

This is where I get stuck. I'm on windows and I don't have docker CLI installed (can't make it work), it looks like I somehow need to push the images to a repository, but from what I've seen I cannot do this unless I have docker CLI (hence docker) running.

Is there any way to push an image to a repository without docker ?
Any other option I could explore ?

Comment: Reading this... it seems you do need docker CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: I realized I could run the docker commands from the VM I'm trying to get rid of. I think I've got it but I'm so so confused with the tagging.